Ruby quirk: Using 'return' to get a nil value
I am doing a problem at Rubymonk where I have to test if an array is 'nil' before doing an operation (adding items inside a nested array but that is not really relevant to the question). I notice, however, if I enter an empty array:
ary.nil? ? nil : ary.map {|x,y=0| x + y }

The code returns 'nil' as desired, but if I do
ary.nil? ? return nil : ary.map {|x,y=0| x + y }

it no longer works.
However, if I do
if ary.nil?
   return nil
 else
   ary.map {|x,y=0| x + y }
 end

the code works as expected and again returns 'nil'.
Why does return nil work in the last instance but not in the ternary expression?
I would have expected the expression return nil to work in both instances.
UPDATE: Thank you @ShadowRanger.  Using parentheses in the ternary addresses my concern. Much appreciated!
ary.nil? ? (return nil) : ary.map {|x,y=0| x + y }


Please post a [MCVE], without the complete function at the very least it's hard to know what you might have done.

Looks like your ternary works if you just use plain return (which returns nil when not given an argument). As does (return nil). Guessing it's an issue with the grammar not allowing return and a value in the middle of a ternary conditional expression like that without parentheses. Ruby's grammar is rather ad hoc at times (it's amazing how often spaces matter, relative to most other languages), this doesn't really surprise me.

Thank you @ShadowRanger! The parentheses restored balance to the force :-).

array is 'nil' makes no sense, as nil.class #=> NilClass, not nil.class #=> Array. Perhaps you mean that a variable ary equals nil. Suppose ary = [[1,2],[4],[5,6]]. Then ary.nil? ? nil : ary.map {|x,y=0| x + y } returns [3, 4, 11], but that array is neither captured to a variable nor acted upon by a method, so the statement has no effect. I therefore do not understand what your mean by "The code works...". Similarly, what do you mean by, "it does not."=? Is an exception raised? Is an incorrect value returned? When discussing code you need to be precise!

If foo has to deal with nil input and as a result might also return nil output, the next method (which processes that output) will need nil handling, too. It might be better to deal with the problem early on, i.e. ensure that ary will never be nil in the first place.

"it does not [work]" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. What doesn't work? How doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ Also, this statement does not make much sense: "I have to test if an array is 'nil'" – An array can never be nil, an array is always an array. Therefore, the whole test is not necessary, and you can remove it.

it's just return, there is no need for nil: ary.nil? ? return : ary.map {|x,y=0| x + y }

return doesn't make much sense inside of an expression like that, and in fact cannot be used in this place. You may want to return explicitly before you do the map:
def foo(ary)
  return nil if ary.nil?
  ary.map { |x| x + 1 }
end

Or the more sensible way to solve this is just to use the safe navigation operator, which will yield nil if ary is nil.
def foo(ary)
  ary&.map { |x| x + 1 }
end

